How to import buefy-next in Vue 3?
As I am migrating my Vue 2 project to Vue 3 and facing some chanllenges about using UI framework Burefy. There is no official support for Vue 3 from Burefy but trying to use buefy-next which extension of Buefy for Vue 3. But Having some problem to use the it at application startup.
As mentioned on docs: https://github.com/ntohq/buefy-next?tab=readme-ov-file#2-import-and-use-buefy, installed buefy-next
"buefy": "npm:@ntohq/buefy-next@^0.1.2",

But when I try to use it in main.ts, it is not working
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';
import {BuefyConfig} from "buefy/types/components";
const config: BuefyConfig = {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
};
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(Buefy, config);

The following error is appearing after this
Overload 1 of 2, '(plugin: Plugin<[BuefyConfig]>, options_0: BuefyConfig): App<Element>', gave the following error.
Argument of type '{ install(Vue: typeof import("./vue3-demo2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), config: BuefyConfig): void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin<[BuefyConfig]>'.
  Type '{ install(Vue: typeof import("./vue3-demo2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), config: BuefyConfig): void; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionPlugin<[BuefyConfig]>'.
    Type '{ install(Vue: typeof import("./vue3-demo2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), config: BuefyConfig): void; }' is not assignable to type '(app: App<any>, options_0: BuefyConfig) => any'.
      Type '{ install(Vue: typeof import("./vue3-demo2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), config: BuefyConfig): void; }' provides no match for the signature '(app: App<any>, options_0: BuefyConfig): any'.


Overload 2 of 2, '(plugin: Plugin<[config: BuefyConfig]>, options: [config: BuefyConfig]): App<Element>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ install(Vue: typeof import("./vue3-demo2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), config: BuefyConfig): void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin<[config: BuefyConfig]>'.
      Type '{ install(Vue: typeof import("./vue3-demo2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), config: BuefyConfig): void; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionPlugin<[config: BuefyConfig]>'.
        Type '{ install(Vue: typeof import("./vue3-demo2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), config: BuefyConfig): void; }' is not assignable to type '(app: App<any>, config: BuefyConfig) => any'.
          Type '{ install(Vue: typeof import("./vue3-demo2/node_modules/vue/dist/vue"), config: BuefyConfig): void; }' provides no match for the signature '(app: App<any>, config: BuefyConfig): any'.
    34 |     defaultLocale: 'en',
    35 | };

  > 36 | app.use(Buefy, config);
       |    

 ^^^^^

Please guide me, what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

The issue is fixed by updating the import statement to
import Buefy from 'buefy/src';
Not sure if this is valid or not, but at least it works.
